# Uploading to AWS (S3 or EBS) with slow/unreliable network connection

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to load a 27MB file to Amazon Web Services and keep loosing the connection with broken pipe or upload failed. Also the connection seems to be extremely slow. I've tried the upload option on their website as well as software such as CyberDuck. Also, tried loading to EBS as well as S3.

Please share any tips or setup that works when uploading large files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to look into using S3 multi-part upload:

> http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html

Each failed part can be retried without losing the parts that were successful.

This can also make your upload go faster as different parts can be uploaded in parallel.

If you don't feel like programming this yourself, a number of software programs and tools sport multi-part upload with S3.